# biblatex includes redundant author initials

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` and `\textcite`, and most citations are appearing correctly with author initials appearing only when needed for disambiguation.  But for just a few authors, the initials are always appearing even though the author names are unique.  I checked that all my bibtex files cite these troublesome authors in exactly the same way.   The surnames are unusual and I am sure they are unique in my bibtex files.   What could cause this?

I have found that it only happens to entries which have a shorthand prefixed to them in the bibliography. E.g. the name Mawer triggers the problem in this entry:

> PN Sx 1 = Mawer, Allen, F. M. Stenton, and with J. E. B. Gover (1929), The place-names of Sussex, part 1, vol. VI, The rapes of Chichester, Arundel and Bramber, Cambridge: English Place-Name Society

The shorthand prefix is created with this code:

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}
    {\printfield{shorthand}\printtext{ = }}}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,backref=true,useprefix=true,hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}
    {\printfield{shorthand}\printtext{ = }}}
\bibliography{%
bibtex/misc_place_names,%
bibtex/EPNS,%
}

\begin{document}
See \textcite{mawer-nth} and \textcite{epns-Bk}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It gives this output when the two entries are in different bibtex files, as in the code above:

See A. Mawer (1920) and Mawer and Stenton (PN Bk).

However, if I put the problem entries in a single bibtex file, the problem goes away.

These are the .bbl entries:

```
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{mawer-nth}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=1,hash=20531a50f8126d9de20c019a74363211}{Mawer}{M\bibinitperiod}{Allen}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=1,hash=20531a50f8126d9de20c019a74363211}{Mawer}{M\bibinitperiod}{Allen}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Cambridge}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {CUP}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{20531a50f8126d9de20c019a74363211}
      \strng{fullhash}{20531a50f8126d9de20c019a74363211}
      \field{sortinit}{M}
      \field{labelyear}{1920}
      \field{labeltitle}{{The place-names of Northumberland and Durham}}
      \field{title}{{The place-names of Northumberland and Durham}}
      \field{year}{1920}
    \endentry
    \entry{epns-Bk}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=4d6093b4a0c2460e6f2882adf13392d7}{Mawer}{M\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=21ae7cedb02db0fa4466cce84219d21e}{Stenton}{S\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{2}{}{%
        {{hash=20531a50f8126d9de20c019a74363211}{Mawer}{M\bibinitperiod}{Allen}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{hash=7e3d1c286187382e0f79c1973fb3b5ea}{Stenton}{S\bibinitperiod}{F.\bibnamedelimi M.}{F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim M\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{shortauthor}{2}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=4d6093b4a0c2460e6f2882adf13392d7}{Mawer}{M\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=21ae7cedb02db0fa4466cce84219d21e}{Stenton}{S\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Cambridge}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {English Place-Name Society}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{3d5595324379f60156ee89ea3274856c}
      \strng{fullhash}{52adbb96b7969c24919cfbabcc553da5}
      \field{sortinit}{P}
      \field{labelyear}{1925}
      \field{labeltitle}{The place-names of Buckinghamshire}
      \field{shorthand}{PN Bk}
      \field{title}{The place-names of Buckinghamshire}
      \field{volume}{II}
      \field{year}{1925}
      \keyw{place-names,England,Buckinghamshire}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
```

Thanks to everyone who commented - it does seem to be the shortauthor field which causing the problem. If this is my bibtex file:

@book{epns-Bk,
  title=    "The place-names of Buckinghamshire",
  author=   "Allen Mawer and F. M. Stenton",
  volume=   {II},
  year=     {1925},
  shorthand={PN Bk},
  shortauthor="Mawer and Stenton",
  publisher={English Place-Name Society},
}

@book{mawer-nth,
  title=    "The place-names of Northumberland and Durham",
  author=   "Allen Mawer",
  year=     "1920",
  publisher="CUP",
  shortauthor="Mawer",
  address=  "Cambridge",
}

with shortauthor in both cases, then there is no problem.  But if shortauthor appears in only one entry, the problem of unwanted initials reappears.  So I'm not sure how I can use shortauthor consistently.

Comment: Can you show us an eaxmple to reproduce that?

Comment: I'd like to, but it's a 600 page book, so getting a small MWE may be difficult, but I'll have a go if it would help.

Comment: I bet if that happens on page 376 all we need is some dummy text, that bibentry which is cited an all the biblatex settings. Build a compilable example around that and test it. Do you see the behaviour? Great, post exactly that code. If it happens on page 502, do the same. Actually, it doesn't matter on which page it happens (i guess).

Comment: It would *really, really* help if we could get that MWE. Without it, the only thing I can say is that normally this feature works quite well. Sometimes it is a problem that for `biblatex` `Donald Knuth` and `Donald E. Knuth` are two different people and they get disambiguated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I'm working on a MWE, but it will take a little time...

Comment: Assuming you are using biber, you can also post just the .bbl code for a particular problem entry (just search for the entry key in the .bbl). We can determine from this whether biber thought that the name needed disambiguating.

Comment: A crucial difference seems to be that you are using the `shortauthor` field in `epns-Bk`. Maybe that has some influence. Please note that normally, a proper MWE also includes the `.bib` entries (not only the `.bbl`, though that can be of help as well).

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely the `shortauthor` field, for `biblatex` `Allen Mawer` and `Mawer` are two different people and because the `shortauthor` is used in the citations you "formally" have one work by `Allen Mawer` and one by `Mawer and Stanton` (but the `Mawer` of `Mawer and Stanton` *is not* `Allan Mawer`). The solution is to get rid of the `shortauthor` field.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here seems to be: don't use `shortauthor`.
In the example you have shown there is no point using `shortauthor` the way you did, `biblatex` can figure that stuff out for itself.
The [`biblatex` docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) say about `shortauthor` (p. 22)

> This field is mainly intended for abbreviated forms of corporate authors

---

If you for some reason need to use `shortauthor`, make sure to still give all names consistently. For `biblatex` `Allen Mawer` is not `Mawer`, so use

```
@book{NASA,
  author = {Allen Mawer and {National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
  shortauthor = {Allen Mawer and {NASA}},
  title = {The Moon Landing},
  year = {1969},
}
```

and not `shortauthor = {Mawer and {NASA}}`, the output will still be "Mawer and NASA" in both cases.

Comment: Yes, I see now that I was using shortauthor to cover up other deficiencies in my methods.  However, I do have a special requirement - say I want to refer to a very well-known author hundreds of times, and there is just one citation of another author of the same surname.  Then I don't really need disambiguation - everybody knows who the well-known author is, and having all the initials every time just clutters up the text.

Comment: @KeithB Well, then either disable the `uniquename` feature or use `shortauthor` for all of your well known authors with only their last names. But then *all* works involving "Allen Mawer" will need a `shortauthor` field where he is only `Mawer`. Since `biblatex` doesn't really know who is famous, there is no real way to automate this, though there might be semi-automatic ways.